# Obfuscating/Randomizing a String

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption, obfuscation

How would I go about obfuscating text so it's unreadable to a user reading a text file, but my program could still read it? Basically, I'm going to have something like `True*True*False*True*False*False*False*True*False*true*` in a text file, and I need it to be all crazy looking.

I know how to get the text from the file and write to the file and all that stuff, I just need to figure out how to obfuscate the string and de-obfuscate it. Is this possible without getting into all crazy encryption stuff? I think AES and other encryption methods are overkill because in my program, this info isn't top secret or something, it can be viewed in the program anyways. I just don't want it edited directly through the file.

Thanks a bunch :D

Nathan

Comment: Real encryption is _easier_ than obfuscation, because the system.security.cryptography namespace makes it almost as easy as creating an object and calling a method of that object. There's no complicated transformation/reversal logic to invent or write yourself.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Steves answer was pretty straight forward, I'll just use that instead. I don't really feel like looking into Security.Cryptography atm :p

Answer (score 8):

> Is this possible without getting into all crazy encryption stuff?

Sure, but if user even remotely knows what he's doing he will be able to decode it with no problem.

```
// Encode
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("true*false*true");
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

// Decode
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); // get string and not bytes, thanks trope
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, having it cracked isn't a problem, as long as you can't view it directly in the text file.  Thanks :D

Comment: For the record, given the situation the OP described, even using encryption isn't secure, as if the program can access the private key so can the user.  You can make it harder than this to access, but it's actually impossible to make it impossible to access.

Comment: @Servy Is this something I should worry about when handling passwords? I'm encrypting and decrypting them with AES right now, I just can't encrypt/decrypt this with AES because the encrypted string is too long for what I'm doing.

Comment: And of course: string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Comment: @Nathan You need to be prepared for the fact that a determined user can unencrypt the file, if they really want to.  If you know users won't want to, or your only trying to deal with ignorant rather than malicious users, then you don't have a problem.  That probably isn't the case for passwords though.

Comment: @Servy It's for a POS system I'm working on, access to passwords would allow tampering with other users, register logs, sales logs, etc. Not sure if I should be worried about this, I'm just a co op student... Is AES enough?

Comment: @Servy can you crack some encrypted string? I would like to encrypt some string myself (don't use any **famous** techniques), just my own tries, if you would like to try, I will be very happy about that. Of course I need time to try it and send to you via email? OK?

Comment: I thing (s)he means if the user has the program used for encryption/decryption, the user will be able to crack a password encrypted with said program

Comment: @KingKing When the private key is given to me, yes, I can crack any encrypted string without any problems, and quite efficiently.  The point here is that the application has no way of "hiding" the key it uses for encyrption.  Anywhere the program will have access to it the user will have access to it.  Now if the code is running on a server somewhere, or calling out to some web service to do the encryption, then that's quite different; in those cases the user won't have access to the key.

Comment: If it's a problem for a determined user to be able to access passwords, you should properly salt and hash, not encrypt, the passwords. (that way, they can't easily be reversed, even by someone with access to the whole system) Similar to what you'd do with a web server storing important user accounts records. E.g. this article talks about how you should and shouldn't: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: Of course, if you're talking about a determined user with physical access to the system, they can use a keylogger or hidden camera to get another user's password pretty easily.

Comment: I think I'll just have to accept the fact that the password is crackable by anyone determined enough. Thanks for all the help guys, I don't think this will be a problem in my program

Comment: @TimS. I'm not sure but looks like some powerful antivirus software can kill keylogger right at the beginning of its life, is there any keylogger which could pass such antivirus softwares? I'm just using `Avira` and looks like it works OK, no way for any keylogger :)

Comment: @KingKing If you update your definitions, popular viruses shouldn't be able to infect you. You could still be vulnerable to newer, more discrete and better coded viruses.

Comment: @Nathan new viruses will use some **special** way to harm you, not the very old one named **key logging**, the behavior is very easy to be detected. As far as I know `keyloggers` died a long time ago and they live only on some bad computers without any updated antivirus softwares.

Comment: @KingKing I highly doubt keyloggers have been 100% abolished, I'm sure new viruses are capable of using "Special ways" to read your keystrokes.